# Inequality for the maximum of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set and $v\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Assume that
$$
\max_{x\in\partial\Omega} |x| >0.
$$
Can we now conclude that there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\max_{x\in\partial\Omega} |x + tv(x)| >0~~~\text{for all }0<t<\varepsilon?
$$

Comment: All $t<\epsilon?$ even negative $t?$

Comment: no you have a point there, I only want $t>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial \Omega$ is compact because it is a closed bounded subset of the closed bounded set $\Omega,$ and it is not empty because $\max_{x\in \partial \Omega}\|x\|>0.$ For any $t\in \Bbb R$ the function  $f_t(x)=\|x+tv(x)\|$ is continuous,  so the image $\{f_t(x):x\in \partial \Omega\}$ is a  non-empty compact subset of $\Bbb R$, which therefore is bounded in $\Bbb R$ and contains a maximum $f(x_1)$ for some  $x_1\in \partial \Omega.$

So $\max_{x\in \partial \Omega}\|x+tv(x)\|$ exists.

Let $x_0\in \partial \Omega$ with $\|x_0\|>0. $ Let $\varepsilon \in \Bbb R^+$ be small enough that $\varepsilon \|v(x_0)\|<\|x_0\|. $Then for all $t\in (0,\varepsilon)$ we have $$\max_{x\in \partial \Omega}\|x+tv(x)\|\ge \|x_0+tv(x_0)\|\ge$$ $$\ge \|x_0\|-\|tv(x_0)\|=$$ $$=\|x_0\|-t\|v(x_0)\|\ge$$ $$\ge \|x_0\|-\varepsilon \|v(x_0)\|>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The proposition that $\max_{x\in S}|x|>0$ is equivalent to $S\neq \{0\}$. So your hypothesis is that $\partial\Omega$ doesn't consist of just the origin, and then you're asking whether for small enough $t$ you also have $\{x+tv(x):x\in\partial\Omega\}\neq\{0\}$. What would it take for that to fail for some particular $t$? We'd need to have $v(x)=-x/t$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$. That condition nails down what $v$ has to do on the whole of $\partial\Omega$, and if it's true for one value of $t$ then it can't possibly be true for any other. So take $\varepsilon$ to be *the* value of $t$ it's true of if there is one, and (say) 1 if there isn't. Then that condition can't hold for $t<\varepsilon$, which means that the original thing in terms of max *does* hold for $t<\varepsilon$, and we're done.

(This seems like a strange question. Is it possible that it should say min rather than max? Or is it a student exercise whose real purpose is to help you learn not to be confused by potentially-confusing things?)

Comment: Mhh you are right there. I broke this question down to what I posted above. My real problem is if this still holds if we have
$\max_{x\in\partial\Omega} (|x|-1)^{n-1} >\alpha$
and want to show that
$\max_{x\in\partial\Omega} (|x+tv(x)|-1)^{n-1} >\alpha$, for some $\alpha>0$ and $0\leq |x| < 2$.

But I think this should be true aswell via the same argument. I think I just got confused there. Thank you.